# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:170)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, illegalargumentexception

I'm creating a api rest with Tomcat 7.0 + Maven + Java EE + JDK 10.0.2 in eclipse and I got this error:

**Error:**

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet api threw exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet api threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception  javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   api threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>
> root cause  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>     jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:170)
>     jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:153)
>     jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:424)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$2.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:104)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:102)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>     java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>     java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>api</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>api</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>10</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20170516</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when the exception occurs?

Comment: @MiguelAlmeida - it happens on servlet initialization.  See the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I figured that the `IllegalArgumentException` is being thrown by Jersey's repackaged ASM library.

I can't be sure I have the right version, but at line 170, the code is like this:

```
    // checks the class version
    // added "support" for java 9 compiled classes
    if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

The code is checking the classfile version number for the class it is attempting to read, and throwing `IllegalArgumentException` if it is too recent.

In short, you are trying to use some Java class that was compiled with a Java compiler that is too new for the ASM library:

- Use an older JDK or set the `-target` version to be older.
- Alternatively, find / install a version of Jersey that is certified for the Java version you are building for.

---

One thing that strikes me as odd is that you have an explicit dependency on an ancient version "asm" in your POM file.   However, the stacktrace indicates that you are not using that version.